# RAID Storage shared between OSs

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, raid

What is the best solution to sharing a RAID array between two OSs?

I'm planning on installing Win7 and Ubuntu in dual boot, either on the same SSD or two seperate. I also want to have two drives in RAID 1 for storage. The motherboard I'm using is an [MSI P67A-GD65 (B3)](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/P67A-GD65--B3-.html). As far as I have understood software-RAID is out of the picture.

The question is how I would solve this in the best possible way? Should I use the onboard "fakeRAID" or get myself a separate controller?

If I use the onboard, what will then happen if the motherboard breaks or needs to be replaced?

I'm new to the whole RAID world and I'm glad for any advice you can give me.

Comment: For a really, really detailed look at RAID, have a look at this question over at our sister site on ServerFalt: http://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into the different types of RAID, 1, 0, 5, etc.. As you have asked you have two types of RAID, Software and Hardware based. FakeRAID is software based. Anything resident on your Motherboard is software based. The differences are many. Basically software RAID is far more susceptible to failure especially if you do not understand how to manage the different types of arrays. Everything in the Soft RAID side is managed via the software on the motherboard so if the motherboard fails or looses power then the RAID dies as well.

Hardware solutions usually stay powered up long enough on their own to allow for proper shutdown and graceful exit on failure. They also have their own dedicated processor(s) and chipsets and memory.

The downside is that a decent Hardware RAID solution will set you back about $400.00 if you have to buy a new Controller.

The upside to whatever you choose is that the OS's on top will be fine in either configuration.

If the Mobo fails and your running software RAID off that mobo you still have the drives and may be able to get it all spun back up, but IDK, never had to do that.

I would recommend that you at least understand [THIS](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/raid-levels-tutorial/)
before configuring a RAID solution that you need to rely on and will use going forward. Once you have made your choice it will be a PITA to switch.

You will loose more data in RAID if you don't understand it than you would on a regular drive.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a great awnser. I will take a deeper look in to my issue and ask myself if it isn't better to stay with one drive for the data and make regular backups of it.